# The bang (!) operator in elm

Tags: elm

What does the bang (or exclamation mark) operator do in elm? I saw an application with an init like this:

```
init = emptyModel ! []
```

I've tried looking in the elm docs, but either there is no info or I couldn't find it:)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The definition of the `!` operator is [here](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.3/Platform-Cmd#!).

It takes a model, a list of commands and returns a tuple (pair) with a model and a single command which is the `batch` of all the commands

Comment: Note that the `!` operator has been removed in Elm 0.19. 

See below:

https://github.com/elm/compiler/blob/master/upgrade-docs/0.19.md#functions-removed